# Single word to represent few things like arriving late, leaving for the day, working from home, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

In a team people would like to communicate to the rest over a chat app to let them know that they are late to office, taking leave, or working from home.

Would like to name a chat group, so looking for a phrase or a single word that can be used as group name (representing the activity)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names for things is explicitly out of scope for our site according to our Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

*Out of office*:

> Out of office indicates that you are not at your usual work place, especially if you are not there at a time when you normally would be.

(source: [yourdictionary.com](https://www.yourdictionary.com/out-of-office))

In some contexts it's exclusively used for leaves (e.g. the so-called Out of Office replies you sometimes receive when sending an email to somebody who is on vacation), but it can also be taken more literally. If you're working from home, you're not in the office but out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got what you are saying but would like to have a name for the group. Can I have a better word or phrase as a name?

Comment: If you're working for Acme Corp, "Acme Corp Out of Office" would work fine. If it's only a single division in the company, use that name instead.